# Seapyを用いたスパーポーズエポック解析　描画が失敗

Tags: python

Seapyを用いてスパーポーズエポック解析をおこなったのですが、中央値と四分位範囲の結果が正しく描画されません。
解決策を教えていただけると嬉しいです。

実行したコードは以下の通りです。

```
import datetime as dt
import spacepy.seapy as sea
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

epochs = sublist['Date_UTC'].to_list()
delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=10)
window= dt.timedelta(hours=1)
sevx = sea.Sea(df_allday['E[mV/m]'], df_allday['index'], epochs, window, delta)
sevx.sea(ci=True)
sevx.plot()
```

実行結果は、写真の通りで、警告文も表示されます。

[image: 実行結果]

警告文

```
UserWarning: Window size changed to 360.0 (points) to fit resolution (0.00011574074074074075)
  warnings.warn(
sea(): datacube added as new attribute
Superposed epoch analysis complete
```

環境は、
macOS Monterey 12.2.1, Python 3.9.12
Seapyのバージョンは0.4.1です。

Answer (score 0):

解決できたわけではないので御参考です。
Seapyモジュールを含む Spacepyの [A Quick Start Documentation](https://spacepy.github.io/quickstart.html) のページ末部の解析例（太陽風速度の時系列データの解析）を基に，データの質と解析結果の関係を調べてみます。
最初に，解析例では半窓は 72ポイント（1時間間隔）ですが，御質問の設定に合わせて 360ポイント（12分間隔）に変更した記述と解析結果（間隔変更前とほぼ同じ）を示します。

```
import datetime as dt
import spacepy.seapy as sea
import spacepy.omni as om
import spacepy.time as spt

epochs = sea.readepochs('SEA_epochs_OMNI.txt')
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=12)
ticks = spt.tickrange(dt.datetime(2005, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2009, 1, 1),
                      delta)
omni12m = om.get_omni(ticks)

# insertion point

window = dt.timedelta(days=3)
sevx = sea.Sea(omni12m['velo'], omni12m['UTC'], epochs, window, delta)
sevx.sea(ci=True)
sevx.plot()
```

[image: 解析結果1]
ここで，`epochs` の各要素に最大 24時間（半窓 3日の 1／3）の乱数値を加減算（下記を上記の `# insertion point` の場所に挿入）して解析してみます。

```
from random import randrange
for i, _ in enumerate(epochs):
    epochs[i] += dt.timedelta(hours=randrange(-24, 25))
```

[image: 解析結果2]
次に，速度の時系列データ（`omni12m['velo']`）の各要素に最大 150km/s（平均 450km/sの 1／3）の乱数値を加減算（下記を上記の `# insertion point` の場所に挿入）して解析してみます。

```
from random import randrange
for i, _ in enumerate(omni12m['velo']):
    omni12m['velo'][i] += randrange(-150, 151)
```

[image: 解析結果3]
これらの結果と御質問の解析結果を見比べた限りでは，御質問の状況は時系列データに問題が生じているのではないかと予想されます。
なお，本質的な話ではありませんが `sevx.sea(ci=True)` は（中央値の） 95％信頼区間の表示になるので四分位範囲の表示なら（デフォルトなので） `sevx.sea()` です。

Comment: 丁寧な説明ありがとうございます！とても参考になりました。時系列データの中身をよく確認して修正しようと思います。